# Control last row label when grouping a dataframe using pandas Grouper

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group a dataframe containing daily indicators by periods of 30 days using `Grouper`:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

n_rows = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(periods=n_rows, end='2020-04-15'), "a": range(n_rows)})
aggregated = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="30D")).sum().reset_index()

print(aggregated.date.max()) 
# out: Timestamp('2020-04-06 00:00:00')
```

The most recent date of `aggregates` changes depending on `n_rows` : I want it to be always the last date of the initial dataframe, such that the last period is ('2020-04-15' - 30D, '2020-04-15').
I would get:

```py
print(aggregated.date.max()) 
# out: Timestamp('2020-04-15 00:00:00')
```

Since I am interested in the most recent groups, I don't care how the first (oldest) group is constructed.

I have tried combinations of parameters `label`, `closed`, `convention`, `loffset`, `base` (documentation[enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=grouper)) but I can't find a working solution:
- My first approach was trying to make sure periods are constucted in the right direction, using  `label="right"` and `closed="right"`, and `convention`, but nothing worked:

```py
aggregated = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="30D", label="right", closed="right")).sum().reset_index()

print(aggregated.date.max()) 
# out: Timestamp('2020-04-16 00:00:00')
```

- Secondly, I tried offsetting the groups without impacting the origin date, using parameters `loffset=f"{n_rows % 30}D"` and/or `base=+/- n_rows % 30`, still nothing.
- Finally I tried building a custom `DateOffset` object but I couldn't find a working exemple with `Grouper`.

I am now wondering if this is even feasible, and am a bit surprised since .

Any suggestion or similar exemple I could look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `resample` you need to use the `base` argument to offset the bins. We can use some remainder division of the entire timespan with the frequency to determine what it needs to be. Then we choose the right label and close on the right (since it's 30D from most recent)

```
base=((df.date.max()-df.date.min())%pd.Timedelta('30D')).days
df.resample('30D', on='date', base=base ,label='right', closed='right').sum()

               a
date            
2020-01-16    45
2020-02-15   735
2020-03-16  1635
2020-04-15  2535


#Similarly with a `pd.Grouper`
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30D', key='date', base=base ,label='right', closed='right')).sum()
```

---

If you're willing to abandon `resample` you can do some very basic math and use a `groupby`. We'll form the 30-day groups from the most recent date and then aggregate

```
grps = (df.date-df.date.max()-pd.Timedelta(days=1)).dt.floor('30D')
df.groupby(grps).agg({'date': 'last', 'a': 'sum'})

                date     a
date                      
-120 days 2020-01-16    45
-90 days  2020-02-15   735
-60 days  2020-03-16  1635
-30 days  2020-04-15  2535
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer : thing is I want to keep using the `Grouper` because I am building on existing code.
I just found out a trivial solution is to update the dataframe so the number of rows is a multiple of my frequency (e.g. 30) : this allows me to use the same code and control how I want to cut or pad the dataframe.

Comment: @kevad I added the same thing with `Grouper`. I think anything you can do with `resample` you can do with a `pd.Grouper`, just a slight change in some of the argument names.

Comment: Thanks, I understand! And you are right, it works with `base=n_rows - r_rows % 30`, no need to affect the dataframe as I implied. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, the working formula for `base` is `n_rows % 30 - 1`